# List all the output created by a SAS step

Tags: sas

Is there a way to get a list of all the outputs (datasets/files) created by a step(iteration) in SAS?
I tried using the automatic variables but all that I could get was the last created dataset using &syslast and &sysdsn variables. But what if a data step creates multiple datasets? How can I get their names/details automatically in SAS without using any list, etc keywords? Is there a way possible?
Please Suggest!
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible.  The only way I can think of is to parse the log following your data step / iteration.

For this you can use something like:

```
/* set up a fresh log prior to your iteration */
%let logloc=%sysfunc(pathname(work))/mylog.txt;
proc printto log="&logloc" new;
run;

/* run your iteration */
data mystep with lots of output datasets;
  set something;
run;

/* return to normal logging */
proc printto log=log; 
run;

data _null_;
  infile "&logloc";
  input;
  if _infile_=:'data' then do;
    /* perform log scanning */
    /* will likely need some complex logic to be robust!*/
  end;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks Allan, I was thinking around the same lines as well and am trying to write a macro which might help submit another task using systask, that can sort of chase the log along with and generate the desired output .

Answer (score 0):

PROC SCAPROC will report this in the log, with the caveat that you have to run the process first and then you'll get the output.

Comment: I would assume that the output would be a lot easier to parse than the regular log at minimum - look for keyword DATASET OUTPUT.